# max number of columns on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

We need a datagridview with more than 2000 columns.

The problem that we have is that only around 700 columns are showing correctly, and the remaining are not showing.

We need to do this because each column represents a day for example: `2009/01/01/` - `2009/01/02`

Does this control have a limit of columns that can show correctly?

Using VS 2010.

Comment: I think showing 2000 column in a grid is not user friendly, there other ways to show data like this.

Comment: I started typing an answer, but gave up.  This is utterly insane.  Two *thousand* columns?

Comment: yeah 2000 columns is crazy but I think that I have another solution for the problem.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507700/datagridview-column-limit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think there's limitation in the count of columns in DataGridView, check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/bd291e0c-dee8-45c1-bee1-54509fdf3c4f/)

I suggest implement it like the calender in Outlook.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of columns you can add is 654. 
This is based on the demo application which I created to check the maximum number of columns.

Steps:

1. Create a Windows Forms Application project in `C#`.
2. Add a `Window From` named "Test" in your project.
3. Drag and drop a `DataGridView` control on your `windows form`.
4. On Load event of the `windows` form write the following code:
5. Execute the  the application (`F5`) and see the number of columns.

   ```
            try
               {
                   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                   {
                       dataGridView1.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
               }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The maximum number of columns you can add is 654