# Datagridview column limit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview table that I need to display some data in. In certain instances, I exceed the column number limit and get the following error:

> Sum of the columns' FillWeight values cannot exceed 65535

Is there any other tool that I could use to overcome this constraint?

Comment: How many columns do you need?

Answer (score 20):

Open a grid event `columnAdded`.

```
private void dataGridViewName_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.FillWeight = 10;    // <<this line will help you
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say a big thank you for this answer which completely solved the problem for me, with very minimal effort.

Answer (score 11):

The default fill weight for a column in the DataGridView is 100. This combined with the maximun combined fill weight for the grid of 65535 means that with `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true you cannot have more than 655 columns in your data source.

If you need more columns than this then the only solution is to set `AutoGenerateColumns` for the grid to false, and then manually add the columns with a different fill weight (I'm not sure if 0 is a valid fill weight, so you may need to use 1).

---

It might be worth your while considering a different design - having so many columns in a DataGridView won't be very usable, the performance of the DataGridView is only tuned for up to 100 columns (I got that figure from [this forum post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.fillweight%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by the DataGridView program manager)

Comment: .NET6, VS2022, Windows.Forms: `column.FillWeight = 0`  results in `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value of '0' is not valid for 'FillWeight'. 'FillWeight' must be greater than 0. (Parameter 'value')
Actual value was 0.'`

Answer (score -5):

If its 65,535 its 16 bit number(since 2^16=65,536). That means you have taken an `Int16` variable. For increasing the limit of this datatype, you should use `Int32` or `Int64` data types.

Comment: This is pure speculation and does not address the context of the problem. You were just making a guess on what you thought made sense.