# OData Source preview error: Sum of columns fill weight cannot exceed 65535

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata, etl

I am using SSIS to create a package and trying to gather data using a OData connection. When i run preview it gives me an error:

> Sum of columns' fill weight cannot exceed 65535

Comment: This is a limitation of the viewer's datagrid that has a max of 65k on width length. I'm afraid you won't be able to use a watcher for this huge size. How many columns are on your flow?

Comment: Have you taken a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507700/datagridview-column-limit ? It may help

Comment: @EzLo The smaller of the two that I am pulling has 1024 columns. The other has more

Comment: @Petaflop I am trying to create an SSIS package not a piece of code

Comment: @jt_de sure, but the underlying reasons may be related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that i was using filter rather than select on my query. They had so many columns that the combined data size exceed Visual Studio limits. Weird thing was it works fine in Excel. Its working now i use select to reduce all the unnecessary columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird to see this error message in SSIS since it is related with datagridview in `.NET` .You may check for many reasons:

## (1) Number of columns

I think that there is a columns count limit in data sources, check that the columns found in the odata source are not very high.

## (2) Preview DatagridView issue

It may be a limitation of the Datagridview used in SSIS `ODATA Source` preview, try to execute the package if it doesn't throw this error. Then this should be the error cause and you cannot do anything about it.

## (3) Columns data type

***(i am not pretty sure that this could be the reason, but it is not bad to give a try)***

I think that the issue is that OData Source is reading a column as `DT_UI2` data type which has a maximum value of `65535`. You have to change this value from the `ODATA Source Advanced Editor`.

Just right-click on the ODATA Source >> Advanced Editor >> Input and Output Properties

And check if there is a column of type `DT_UI2` or `DT_I2` and change it to `DT_I4`