# Datatable doesnot show rows while reading tsv file

Tags: c#, datatable

[image]AM reading .tsv file which has around 3500 columns and 1000 rows , when i add rows to data table , rows are added to data table successfully( i see datatable.Rows.Count is increasing) but data table doesn't show any data. i have referred various articles,still see same issue, any suggestions would help me

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Latest PM File.tsv");
        char[] delimiter = new char[] { '\t' };
        string[] columnheaders = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
        foreach (string columnheader in columnheaders)
        {
            datatable.Columns.Add(columnheader); // I've added the column headers here.
        }

        while (streamreader.Peek() > 0)
        {
            DataRow datarow = datatable.NewRow();
            datarow.ItemArray = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
            datatable.Rows.Add(datarow);
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a fewer number of rows to check if it works?

Comment: what did you mean by "data table doesn't show any data"? is it bound to some UI which then does not show any data?

Comment: Tried with fewer rows, but no luck@PriyankPanchal

Comment: @Rex added a snippet of datatable

Comment: @Venkat, not sure how you use DS visualizer for; but if for debug purpose only, you might want to just write out the dataTable/dataset to xml file on the fly to see whether contents are in. in general, when you are busy inserting into a in-memory object, if you use any kind of visual insepctor, you might see nothing due to UI binding which does not auto-refresh most of the time. so I would suggest you try different way to check the contents (that's why i suggested you try save down the content to xml...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment on my other answer:

Your TSV contains 5735 columns. My dataset visualizer stops (crashes??) after 655 columns. The data is there; it can be seen in the immediate window:

[image]

Notes on this screenshot:

- Some of your column headers are identical and give rise to a "column already belongs in table" error. I added an incrementing number on the end of the name to resolve this (highlighted yellow `hdr` variable
- You can see in th snip of the visualizer, that it's got up to column 655 (0-654) and crashed/stopped

And a further observation:

The test file you posted doesn't seem to contain more than 57 columns of data. If this is true for the whole file, some data repairs may be in order. As observed, the column header list contains duplicates; if the data is mangled into being diagonally represented (new column added for data that should be in an existing column) you might have to put more effort in to turning it back to the minimal number of columns. A datatable with nearly 6000 columns is going to be a complete pain in the ass to query

Comment: Dataset visualizer uses the DataGridView control and this one has its limits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507700/datagridview-column-limit

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, I wasn't able to reproduce your problem:

[image]

Nor with this simplified version (doesn't treat first line as headers):

[image]

Here's the slightly simpler code I used:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add("col" + i);

        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\a.tsv"))
            dt.Rows.Add(line.Split('\t'));

        int c = dt.Rows.Count; //not necessary, just makes for an easy place to put a breakpoint
    }
}
```

Wondering what result you get if you paste it verbatim. Perhaps your dataset visualizer is broken (restart VS?)

Try typing this into the Immediate Window:

```
?datatable.Rows[0].ItemArray
```

You should see a rendering of the array as text:

[image]

If so, proceed with your coding; the datatable contains data it's just that your visualizer is not showing it for some reason.

ps; I get into the visualizer by pointing to "datatable" then clicking the magnifying glass in the tooltip

Comment: That test file contains duplicate names for columns. It raises an exception with the code posted in the question